# Add View to TableViewController with NavigationController

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

For adding a view to a `UITableViewController` I added the view to `navigationController` as below:

```
self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(view)
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.navigationController?.view.rightAnchor)!).isActive = true
view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.navigationController?.view.bottomAnchor)!).isActive = true
view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
```

But when you want to push a new `ViewController` it will keeps the added view (`myView`).

I tried to add `myView` to `view` and `tableView` like below:

```
self.view.addSubview(myView)
self.tableView.addSubview(myView)
```

but both doesn't work.
I know I can use `UIViewController` and add a `UITableView` and then it is easier to add `myView` to `UIViewController`.

Should I add `myView` to another view?

Answer (score 1):

The View of a UITableViewController is a UITableView, so you cannot add subviews to the controller on top of the table.

You have to derive from UIViewController to get full layout control.
Instead of using UITableViewController, use a UIViewController and put a UITableView within it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible in UITableViewConroller:

```
   let bottomView = UIView()
    bottomView.backgroundColor = .red // or your color
    bottomView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 78, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 78) // 78 or your size of view
    navigationController?.view.addSubview(bottomView)
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    bottomView.backgroundColor = .red // or your color
    bottomView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 78, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 78) // 78 or your size of view
    navigationController?.view.addSubview(bottomView)
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()[enter image description here][1]
```